# In R: data.table html export: ¶ characters

Tags: html, r

When I export a data.table as html on top of the html output are a line of these charakters  ¶ ¶ ¶ ¶ ¶ ¶ ¶ ¶ ¶ ¶ ¶ ¶ ¶ ¶ ¶ ¶ ¶ ¶ ¶ ¶

How can I replace them? Is it a title?
As a side question: is it possible to have text at the bottom of the HTML? I use a caption on top of the table. Can I add more text below the table?

see picture:
[image]

```
setwd("..")
DB <- DT::datatable(iris, caption = paste0("fsdf", "sdfsdf", sep=" "),
        rownames = FALSE,
                           extensions = 'Buttons',
                           options = list(autoWidth = TRUE,
                                          extensions = 'FixedColumns',
                                          options = list(dom = 't',
                                                         scrollX = TRUE,
                                                         fixedColumns = TRUE),
                                          dom=('Bfrtip'),
                                          buttons = c('excel', 'csv'),
                                          pageLength = nrow(iris),
                                          searchHighlight = TRUE),
                           filter=list(position="top"))
DT::saveWidget(DB, paste0("name",format(Sys.time(),"%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S"),".html"))
```

Comment: This doesn't appear when I run your code - perhaps it is something with the browser?

Comment: I tested it with FF, Chrome, edge, IE - all show the same characters